# Visual Studio C++ intellisense Function Info - How to interpret the various delimiters, types, and acronyms

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax, stl, intellisense

I am experienced with classic C, C++, but I am now learning how to use the various "newer" resources in the C++ Standard Library.

In Visual Studio, when I start typing a function name, I get a "quick info" definition, with several fields. Usually the function name is preceded by a long list of libraries, parent classes, template typename(s), etc.

How do I interpret these various fields?

Using the std::tuple get<>() function, here is a typical example for VS intellisense popups (with cursor positions shown in **red**.)

[image: cursor selecting the template typename]

[image: cursor selecting the args]

I understand that intellisense is first highlighting the template typename, then highlighting the function argument(s).

But how do I make sense of the other fields, *preceding* the function-name?

**For example:** `constexpr std::tuple_element_t<_ldx, std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>> &` get<_Idx,_Ty1,_Ty2>(...)

Comment: I edited your question because the removed portion is off-topic for stack-overflow. Otherwise seems like a good question, which is why I edited and didn't flag for closure instead.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue, if the Eugene's answer helps to resolve your issue, you can consider marking it as answer. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

What is preceding function name is it's return type, which in this case is pretty long template with it's arguments.